# Are there physical systems for which Hamiltonian is not defined?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

Consider the following Lagrangian :
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}\sin^2q$$
It's easy to see for such a lagrangian we can't find the Hamiltonian since
$$p=\partial_{\dot{q}}\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\sin^2q$$
We can't write $\dot{q}$ as function of $p$. Technically saying, Legendre transform doesn't exist. I'm asking if there can be systems which describe by such Lagrangians.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298172/2451

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact calculate the Hamiltonian to your Lagrangian! But first
let us take a look at the Lagrangian proposed by OP.
What are the dynamics?

The EoM obtained by the EL-equations are
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac 1 2 \sin^2 q - \dot q \sin q \cos q = 0\\
\sin  q \cos q \dot q - \dot q \sin q \cos q = 0\\
0 = 0
$$
Hence the Lagrangian seemingly describes no dynamics. Lets go back to your original question and check for the Hamiltonian. The Hamiltonian is given by
$$
H = p \dot q - L = \frac 1 2 \sin^2 q \dot q - L = 0
$$
Again no dynamics. So one has to be sure that you have a propagating degree of freedom, hence you should be sure about the kinetic term in your theory.
So here you dont have a kinetic term.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @AlmostClueless's answer:

The reason your Lagrangean does not describe any dynamics is that it is a total time derivative,
$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}\sin^2q=\frac14 \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(q-\sin q \cos q\right)\,.
$$